# Create a Download Redirect page

Tags: php, forms, redirect, process, download

I have a form where the user selects the images she wants to download, and then process_form.php does the dirty work of creating a zip file and putting the images that the user wanted into that zip file, and finally preparing the download, like this:

```
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=images.zip");
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
readfile("images.zip");
```

The download happens as soon as the user hits the "Submit" button on the form.

I want to create a page that say something like:

> Your download will begin automatically. If it doesn't, click here.

The advice I've gotten is make an "intermediate" page which would then trigger the download using javascript.

```
location.href='process_form.php'
```

Ok, Done. So, now, this new "intermediate" page creates a zip file and throws it on da serva, and displays "your download should bla bla bla", and javascript redirects to the process_form.php. BUT, all I see is a blank page, even through there is HTML in the "intermediate" page,  after the closing } of the `if(isset($_POST)` bit of PHP.......So, why is my page blank?

### Solution

Use HTML instead.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=process_ads.php">
```

That works.

Comment: Add your answer below and mark that as the accepted answer please.

Comment: I can't, not enough rep points :(

Comment: Of course you can. It takes 1 Rep to answer a question.

Comment: @Rikudo Users with less than 100 rep have to wait 8 hours before they can answer their own question.

Comment: Nice to know :-o. I'll just post it as community wiki so no reputation gain. Afterwards he can post his own answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

From OP's own answer:

> ### Solution
>
> Use HTML instead.
>
> ```
> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=process_ads.php">
> ```
>
> That works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=images.zip");
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
readfile("images.zip");
header("refresh: 2; url=process_form.php");
```